Google Play keeps rejecting my TV application due to "No login credentials provided"
anybody here to help me out?
Google keeps rejecting my TV app due to "login not provided" however I have provided many times in app actions the login credentials even tried to state that there is no login just in case.
I have added logging if the TV app is launched at all for the following version code but I do not see them launching the app despite sending the app for review 20x times, automatically rejected after 5 minutes when sent for review - are these handled by physical people or it is an automated flow?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic/272167
